# I am using raspberry pi 4 , raspbian os. I can't print or type Combined indic fonts properly. But in window os it's working properly

Tags: fonts

name_hindi = "अभिव्यक्त करना"

name_gujrati = "વ્યક્ત"

print(name_gujrati+name_hindi)

// '''this both hindi and Gujarati combined font not print or display properly in raspberry pi python code '''

---

एक्सप्रेस
I want this type of font but. It's printing not properly combined word. I am using raspberry pi thonny.

Comment: what programming language is that?

Comment: I'm going to assume your question included the Python snippet and this is the string you're trying to type: `ભાવનગર એभावनगर ए`. When you say you "can't type" -- what terminal are you using, how are you logged into your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: It looks like the code is python (python3) but pasting the code is made difficult because of the line breaks without being formatted as code.  It's not actually failing because of the OS type, but because of the font set up in the window/terminal where you type.
On the Pi, try changing the *font* (or running another type of terminal) to something that supports your locale's characters.  In my terminal, my favourite font `Fantasque Sans Mono` won't show these characters, they show up as blanks.  Copying the blanks to an editor shows a good string. In xfce4-terminal, the same font is good too.